# NGINX reverse proxy / port-forwarding rule to send http traffic to port 3000 for my Node Express application causes the application to be unusable

Tags: node.js, linux, nginx

I had a Node JS server running with Express, that is being used as a web server. It connects to my database to run queries for the end user.

I have a VPS set up on Digital Ocean, with a Node App running on port 3000. When I access the Node app on ip:3000 it runs fine and as fast as to be expected. If I set up a reverse proxy with nginx, or a firewall rule that forwards traffic from port 80 to port 3000, parts of the page seem to run extremely slowly, or not at all. I can't seem to find a link as to why, as some of the database queries run fine, but some don't load at all and cause the page to hang. If I access the site using port 3000, the site still continues to run fine, even with nginx running. It's only the access from port 80 that is slow.

My NGINX conf is:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
          # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/$
        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##
server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}
```

My example.com file is (where 'example.com' is my site address):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/example.com/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your nginx config?

Comment: Try setting these settings:


log_not_found off;
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_no_cache 1;
proxy_cache_bypass 1;

And also use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

Comment: @ZachLeighton Still the same result unfortunately

Comment: You can add some logging and try and see what's causing it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using PM2 to start instance of your node app in production https://github.com/Unitech/pm2

Try following NGINX configurations

```
upstream prod_nodejs_upstream {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
    keepalive 64;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /home/www/example;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
        proxy_pass http://prod_nodejs_upstream/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_read_timeout 240s;
    }
}
```

Once these changes applied you must restart NGINX using commands `sudo nginx -t` and then `sudo systemctl restart nginx`

Comment: This has not resolved the issue. Same result as previous.

Comment: Do one thing, try accessing node app directly using 3000 port like http://example.com:3000/. Check if it is running slow or fast.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, it works fine with the port specified.

Comment: In `proxy.conf` file of NGINX please configuration

```
proxy_buffers           32 4m;
proxy_busy_buffers_size     25m;
proxy_buffer_size 512k;
proxy_ignore_headers "Cache-Control" "Expires";
proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
client_max_body_size        1024m;
client_body_buffer_size     4m;
proxy_connect_timeout 300;
proxy_read_timeout 300;
proxy_send_timeout 300;
proxy_intercept_errors off;
```

Comment: After removing duplicate rows, this still has the same result.

Comment: There is some other issue which is causing it. I recommend testing from your VM by typing command to test response time on server `curl -O http://localhost/` and `curl -O http://example.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Please update configuration with as below and share output of file so that time taken by upstream can be measured

```
upstream prod_nodejs_upstream {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
    keepalive 64;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /home/www/example;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
        proxy_pass http://prod_nodejs_upstream/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_read_timeout 240s;
    }

    log_format apm '"$time_local" client=$remote_addr '
               'method=$request_method request="$request" '
               'request_length=$request_length '
               'status=$status bytes_sent=$bytes_sent '
               'body_bytes_sent=$body_bytes_sent '
               'referer=$http_referer '
               'user_agent="$http_user_agent" '
               'upstream_addr=$upstream_addr '
               'upstream_status=$upstream_status '
               'request_time=$request_time '
               'upstream_response_time=$upstream_response_time '
               'upstream_connect_time=$upstream_connect_time '
               'upstream_header_time=$upstream_header_time';

}
```